# using fetch api function to get data from MongoDB and display them in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, fetch

I have a node application which inserts different types of courses into mongodb and displays them onto the web page directly from the database. i want to use the fetch() api function to get the data from mongodb by passing the data into json format and then displaying them using the ejs engine

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/studentdb')
var db=mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.log.bind(console, "connection error"));
db.once('open', function(callback){
    console.log("connection succeeded");
})


app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    // fetch and sort course collection by id in descending order
    req.db.collection('course').find().sort({"_id": -1}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        //if (err) return console.log(err)
        if (err) {
            req.flash('error', err)
            res.render('user/list', {
                title: 'User List',
                data: ''
            })
        } else {
            // render to views/user/list.ejs template file
            res.render('user/list', {
                title: 'User List',
                data: result
            })
        }
    })
})

// SHOW ADD course FORM
app.get('/add', function(req, res, next){
    // render to views/user/add.ejs
    res.render('user/add', {
        title: 'Add course',
        topic: '',
        price: '',
        location: '',
        provider:'',
        review_rankings: '',
        author_ranking: ''
    })
})


app.post('/add', function(req,res, next){
    var topic = req.body.topic;
    var price =req.body.price;
    var location = req.body.location;
    var provider = req.body.provider;
    var review_rankings = req.body.review_rankings;
    var author_ranking =req.body.author_ranking;

    var data = {
        "topic": topic,
        "price":price,
        "location":location,
        "provider":provider,
        "review_rankings":review_rankings,
        "author_ranking": author_ranking
    };

    db.collection('course').insertOne(data,function(err, collection){


        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Record inserted Successfully");

    });

    return res.redirect('/users');



})
```

I want to use the fetch api function like the code below using mongodb and displaying the information to the web page

```
fetch('http"//reqres.in./api/users', {

    method:'POST',
    headers:{
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    },

    body: JSON.stringify({

        name:'user 1'
    })

}).then(res => {
    return res.json()

})
.then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.log('ERROR'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fetch API is not available out of the box for NodeJS applications. You can use the `node-fetch` package to get a similar API (there are some [known differences](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/HEAD/LIMITS.md) though), or use other libraries like Axios.

The solution without using external packages would be to use the native `http` module (using the `request` method documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback))